# UITableview Scrollable Issues

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am in the process of adding all of my data to my iPhone application, the coding is done other than hard coding the data into it. I have run into an issue. I am using UITableviews and I am adding around 150-250 items per table view, it allows me to add the data, but when I run it won't let me scroll down past about 12 items. I would like to be able to scroll through all 200+ of my items, but as I said it only allows the first 12 or so. I will post a snippet of my code below.

**RootTableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootTableViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

**RootTableViewController.m**

```
#import "RootTableViewController.h"
#import "SecondTableViewController.h"

@interface RootTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation RootTableViewController
{
NSArray *states;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

states = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Alabama", @"Georgia", @"Tennessee", @"Colorado", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [states count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//table identifier
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"StateCell";

//creating a cell
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

//if cell doesn't have anything in it, creates a new one
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

//creates text for cell, depending on what row it is
cell.textLabel.text = [states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:17];

return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
//push segue identifier 'showArrayDetail'
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showStateDetail"])
{
    //row that we clicked on
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    //'SecondTableVieController' object is created
    SecondTableViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    //sets 'stateName' to what row you pick
    destViewController.stateName = [states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //sets title to 'stateName' you picked
    destViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Areas", destViewController.stateName];
}
}

@end
```

**SecondTableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *stateName;

@end
```

**SecondTableViewController.m**

```
#import "SecondTableViewController.h"
#import "ThirdTableViewController.h"

@interface SecondTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondTableViewController
{
NSArray *areas;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//populating arrays
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"Alabama":@[@"Moss Rock Preserve Boulder Fields", @"Alabama Area 2", 
@"Alabama Area 3"], @"Georgia": @[@"Georgia Area 1", @"Georgia Area 2", @"Georgia Area 3"], 
@"Tennessee":@[@"Tennessee Area 1", @"Tennessee Area 2", @"Tennessee Area 3"], 
@"Colorado":@[@"Colorado Area 1", @"Colorado Area 2", @"Colorado Area 3"]};

areas = dict[self.stateName];



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return areas.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"AreaCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
cell.textLabel.text = areas[indexPath.row];
return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
//push segue identifier 'showArrayDetail'
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showAreaDetail"])
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    ThirdTableViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.areaName = areas[indexPath.row];
    destViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Climbs", destViewController.areaName];
}
}

@end
```

**ThirdTableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ThirdTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *areaName;

@end
```

**ThirdTableViewController.m**

```
#import "ThirdTableViewController.h"
#import "FourthTableViewController.h"

@interface ThirdTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation ThirdTableViewController
{
NSArray *climbs;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//populating arrays
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"Moss Rock Preserve Boulder Fields":@[@"Tesseract", @"Chalky Dreams",   
@"Aristocratic Nose", @"Bee Stings", @"Recovery Run Traverse", @"Heel Shock", @"Fourth of July", 
@"No Sack", @"Poop Dreams", @"Hoop Dreams", @"Grass Man Traverse", @"Mikey Likes It", @"Just 
Throw", @"Rapture"], @"Georgia Area 1": @[@"Georgia Climb 1", @"Georgia Climb 2", @"Georgia 
Climb 3"], @"Tennessee Area 1":@[@"Tennessee Climb 1", @"Tennessee Climb 2", @"Tennessee Climb 
3"], @"Colorado Area 1":@[@"Colorado Climb 1", @"Colorado Climb 2", @"Colorado Climb 3"]};

climbs = dict[self.areaName];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return climbs.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ClimbCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
cell.textLabel.text = climbs[indexPath.row];
return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
 //push segue identifier 'showArrayDetail'
 if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showClimbDetail"])
 {
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
     FourthTableViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
     destViewController.climbName = climbs[indexPath.row];
     destViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Specs", destViewController.climbName];
 }

 }

@end
```

**FourthViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FourthTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *climbName;

@end
```

**FourthViewController.m**

```
#import "FourthTableViewController.h"

@interface FourthTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation FourthTableViewController
{
NSArray *specs;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//populating arrays
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"Tesseract":@[@"Alabama Spec 1", @"Alabama Spec 2", @"Alabama Spec 3"], 
@"Georgia Climb 1": @[@"Georgia Spec 1", @"Georgia Spec 2", @"Georgia Spec 3"], @"Tennessee 
Climb 1":@[@"Tennessee Spec 1", @"Tennessee Spec 2", @"Tennessee Spec 3"], @"Colorado Climb 
1":@[@"Colorado Spec 1", @"Colorado Spec 2", @"Colorado Spec 3"]};

specs = dict[self.climbName];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return specs.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SpecCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
cell.textLabel.text = specs[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:17];

return cell;
}
```

I was thinking I needed to add a "scrollable section" like I would in a Java application, but it is already scrollable....

Thanks

Comment: What array/dictionary do you use to populate the tableView? If you use `climbs` in this case, you will only get approximately 3 items. Please provide your code for `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: @Emil Sorry, just added the remainder of my code for that class that should better show my issue

Comment: what is the content of self.areaName?

Comment: Depending on what your `self.areaName` is, there will only be either 14 or 3 values present in the tableView.

Comment: I just added the other 2 classes where you can see the functionality of "self.areaName".

Comment: Set a break point at numberOfRowsInSection delegate and see how does the `climbs` array is.
Can you make sure that the data in it are correct (150-200 records)?

Comment: Right now I only have 14 climbs in the first area "Moss Rock Preserve Boulder Fields", but it only lets me see the first 12.... If I were to add 200, it would still only allow me to see the first 12

Comment: Could you update your whole project to here? That would be more easier to resolve the problem.

Comment: Yes, I will post all of my classes above

Comment: Ok, just added the remainder of my code, in correct order @Envil

Comment: Some `cellForRowAtIndexPath` implementation is missing `if(cell == nil)`. Please correct that to see whether it causes the problem or not. @javaGeek

Comment: That didn't fix the problem....I added it in the 3 classes that were missing

Comment: When you reach to the end of the table, you can still stretch it up a little bit right? When you do that, is there any cell that has data but was hidden outside the frame of the tableView?
If so, please check the frame of the tableView. @javaGeek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I move the correct comment to here.

When you reach to the end of the table, you can still stretch it up a little bit right? When you do that, is there any cell that has data but was hidden outside the frame of the tableView? If so, please check the frame of the `tableView`.